# Python calculate correlation of a column against entire dataframe grouped by index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I have a dataframe of size (109049, 29184) that looks like this:

```
df:
      Ford Honda GM
index           
Sedan   4   1   8
Sedan   5   2   7
Sedan   6   3   6
Sedan   7   4   5
SUV     8   5   7
SUV     1   6   6
SUV     2   7   5
SUV     3   8   4
```

This data frame has 22 different indexes. I want to calculate correlation for column Ford against all the other columns broken down by index in this way:

```
index   SUV      Sedan
        Ford     Ford
Ford    1.00     1.0
Honda   -0.58    1.0
GM      0.58     -1.0
```

I tried to calculate correlation across the entire data using this:

```
df.groupby('index').corr(method = 'spearman').reset_index()
```

But due to huge data size, I am unable to calculate even after the running the code for more than 10 hours. How can I calculate the correlation for one column against rest of the columns broken down by index in a quick way?

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what youre looking for?

```
s = df.groupby(level=0).corr()
s.unstack(level=0)['Ford']
```

Output:

```
index       SUV  Sedan
Ford   1.000000    1.0
Honda -0.581318    1.0
GM     0.581318   -1.0
```